# How topic QOS effect DDS service?

Tags: publish-subscribe, data-distribution-service

Most of the Topic Qos policies are also applicable to DataWriter and DataReader. For example DURABILITY, DEADLINE, LATENCY_BUDGET, RELIABILITY etc.

What happen when this type of Qos policies set with different values at Topic and its DataWriter or DataReader?

Is it considered as incompatible request? Is there a hierarchy between  Topic and DataWriter or DataReader Qos policies?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the DataReader/DataWriter QoS different from the Topic QoS is allowed. The only really significant role of the Topic QoS in DDS is when the durability kind is set to Transient/Persistent (an optional feature). In that case, the middleware ensures the data remains available even when all application processes are stopped (but some middleware ones remain in the case of transient).

The data set the middleware retains is what a DataReader that copied its QoS from the Topic QoS would contain. When copying the QoS for this purpose, the history kind/depth and resource limits settings are taken from the DurabilityService setting; and the mechanism also includes some automatic cleanup of disposed data (the "service cleanup delay" part of the DurabilityService setting).

Therefore, if a DataWriter and a Topic both have the durability kind set to transient/persistent, you can get incompatible QoS notifications if the QoS's are otherwise incompatible.

My advice is always to think carefully about the QoS when you're thinking about the topics you need, then set the Topic QoS accordingly. Almost always, you can then let the DataReaders and the DataWriters inherit from the Topic QoS.